# Electrical Engineering SE Anniversary Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know Electrical Engineering SE’s anniversary of its graduation is coming up on **March 21st**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events are a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention (community@stackexchange.com). We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “go for it!”

Comment: how did they manage for the prizes in SuperUser contest?

Comment: @clabacchio If there is sufficient support and you can organize and launch a useful community-run celebration/contest/etc, we are willing to reciprocate in kind with the funds for prizes or whatever financial support is needed.

Comment: It seems that this topic is not getting a lot of attention, but I would like to bring this event to the next step. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

My lack of fantasy and experience suggests to mimic that contest, just eventually excluding the blog part, since we haven't a blog (even though it may be cool).